# C++ Compilation error when using async with Templates

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am trying to create a new thread with a recursive function call to the function itself:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, &CQSort<typename T>::qSort1, arr, start, p-1);
```

p is declared as an int as a local variable.

The method qSort1 is implemented as

```
template <typename T>
void CQSort<typename T>::qSort1(T &arr, int start, int end)
{...}
```

I am getting a compilation error in the async call.

```
Error   C2672   'std::async': no matching overloaded function found
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with the full code and full error message

Comment: At a guess you need `std::async(std::launch::async, &CQSort<typename T>::qSort1,this, std::ref(arr), start, p-1);`

Comment: `&CQSort<typename T>::qSort1` -> `&CQSort<decltype(arr)>::qSort1`.

Comment: Also `this, std::ref(arr)`

Comment: The change suggested by @AlanBirtles and rafix07 solved the compilation Error. Thanks.